# Find the command being used to launch a GUI application

Tags: terminal, gnome, gui, .desktop

I'm running Fedora Linux with the Gnome desktop environment and I'm looking to create .desktop entries for applications that don't have them. In this case, I'd like to add two entries: one for the GSConnect gnome extension and a separate one for the Messaging portion of GSConnect. How do I find out what action is being performed when I open GSConnect from the Extension Manager and likewise when I open Messaging from within GSConnect? Is there a general way to launch an application normally and then view some log to see what command is being run in the background?

Comment: That's not an application; you could call it a plugin, if you will. Could you describe what exactly you want to happen when you run that .desktop file?

Comment: other than that, are you maybe looking for [its CLI tool documentation](https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki/CLI-Scripting)?

Comment: Thank you, @MarcusMüller. I'm simply looking to open GSConnect with the .desktop file. The CLI documentation should show me what's possible.

Comment: I think @MarcusMüller has pointed you in the right direction. But to answer you actual question: [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) is the command to view a log of what the system is actually doing and would show new processes as system-level exec calls.

Comment: Time to dig into the `strace` man pages. Thank you!